# HSTS enabled site and Penetration test

Tags: c#, .net, security, hsts

I setup our .NET web application so that it has [HSTS](https://nvisium.com/blog/2014/04/25/is-your-site-hsts-enabled.html) enabled.  I verfied this by going to https://gf.dev/hsts-test and put in our URL and it shows that HSTS protection is there.

The result shows:

> Strict-Transport-Security  max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains

However, our client comes back saying it is still not the case.  They told us while our main URL is HSTS enabled, the test vector URL is not.

For example:

1. Go to https://gf.dev/hsts-test
2. Put in https://nvisium.com and click Test Header
3. Result shows it is HSTS enabled.
4. Do the test again but put in https://nvisium.com/test.xml  (test.xml does not exist)
5. Result shows it is not HSTS enabled.

If I put the URL to an existed resource that it passes the HSTS test.

My question is do they have a point? or is this a false positive test in one of the Penetration test software they use?

Playing devil's advocate, I can only argue that if you request a non-existence resource, the web site still sends a response back and that it does not force the client to use hsts.

Comment: You might have better luck asking this question here: https://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

This same question is posted on security stackexchange and Esa Jokinen answers it [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/231672/should-i-return-an-hsts-header-for-404-error-pages).